# Not able to access Flask Service running in docker from outside the docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have created a flask service inside docker

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return "App is working"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", debug=False)
```

But I am not able to access above service from outside the docker.

My `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM python:3.7

MAINTAINER sociopath(xyz@gmail.com)

COPY requirements.txt domain.yml config.yml /tmp/
COPY data /tmp/data
COPY helper /tmp/helper
COPY models /tmp/models
COPY app.py /tmp/app.py

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

I build it using command

`docker build . -t cont1`

and run it using

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name c1 cont1`

When I send the request from inside the docker I get `App is working` but no response when I try to access from my machine.

**Edit**

I have windows OS in which I'm using Ubuntu VM where docker is installed.
I get response on Ubuntu but When I try to access the same from windows I received an error.

Comment: How are you trying to access the container from the host?  I'd expect that trying to reach port 5000 on the VM's IP address (which will not be `localhost`) would work.

Comment: So I have to use VM's IP not Docker's IP?

Comment: You should probably ignore the detail that containers have IP addresses; you can't directly reach them except in one very specific host setup.  Treat the container the same way you would a server running directly on the VM on port 5000.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze  it worked. Though I'm not sure why it is working on VM and docker both

Answer (score 0):

Expose your docker file to an external source(Listener)([Ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/))

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

Ex:-

```
FROM python:3.7

MAINTAINER sociopath(xyz@gmail.com)

COPY requirements.txt domain.yml config.yml /tmp/
COPY data /tmp/data
COPY helper /tmp/helper
COPY models /tmp/models
COPY app.py /tmp/app.py

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```