# Can't access flask site outside Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm running Linux Mint with Python 3.6.

I have read through every link on here but can't figure out what is wrong. I am running a simple flask app which works fine when I'm running it locally on my machine, but then running it with Docker I can't access the IP in my browser.

I have set the flask app to run on host `0.0.0.0`, with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`.

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir -p /var/app

WORKDIR /var/app

COPY . /var/app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["pytest", "-v", "tests/test_flask_api.py"]
# CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
CMD ["python3", "-m", "Flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

### docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: ./app
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
```

After running the command `docker-compose up -d` to build and run the container, I run the command `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'` to get the IP address of the container as `172.17.0.2`.

I try to access the site via `172.17.0.2:5000` and `localhost:5000`, but both just hang and don't load.

Finally, I ran `docker exec -it restapimma_web_1 /bin/bash` to get into the container. Then I ran `curl localhost:5000` and was able to get the correct response. So the flask app is running inside the container I just can't access it outside the container.

Comment: Have you tried exposing 5000?

Comment: Yes, no help though.

Comment: @Sociopath I got the IP of the docker container by running `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'`, which was `172.17.0.2`. But `172.17.0.2:5000` won't load for me.

Comment: docker IP can only be used for Apps inside the docker but if you want to access from outside the docker use Host machine's IP i.e. *IP of machine on which docker is installed*

Comment: @Sociopath sorry for all the questions, do you have a command to run this? From what you're describing, `localhost` should work.

Comment: Few days back I had posted similar question. Check comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045563/not-able-to-access-flask-service-running-in-docker-from-outside-the-docker)

Comment: Problem was I couldn't access the `http://172.17.0.2:5000` IP because I had a VPN running. Any ideas why I a VPN would cause this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. To get it working:

1. Allow your flask app to accept a HOST argument from your environment

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        host=os.environ.get("BACKEND_HOST", "172.0.0.1"),
        port=your_port,
        debug=True,
    )
```

2. set your host environmental var in your composition

```
services:
  [your service name]:
    image:[your image]
    environment:
      - BACKEND_HOST=[your service name]
    ports:
      - "[etc]"
```

Basically flask wants to be called using the right hostname